# Maximize product of numbers

Tags: algorithm, math

Given a number `n` and partition value `k`, such that `n1+n2+..nk=n`, I need to find the set `{n1,n2..,nk}` such that `n1*n2*...nk` is maximum.

One method of solving this would be listing out all the subsets and then finding the one with the maximum product. Is there any algorithm that is efficient (anything better than brute force)?

To find subsets, this formula can be used and I am currently developing using [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SubsetSumProblem.html) logic.

Comment: What are the `k` subsets? Is `n1,n2,...nk` are part of some subset you have? or you can "invent" them?

Comment: Sort them, multiply the `k` largest together.  If you have to deal with negative numbers it gets a little more complicated, but only a little.

Comment: @amit I'm sorry, there are no `k` subsets. I meant all the possible subsets that can result for the subset `{n1,...nk}`.

Comment: I'm still confused by the problem description, sorry.  You have some numbers, and you need to choose a subset of them that (a) meets certain requirements and (b) maximises some objective function.  I *think* the requirement (a) is that the subset has to sum to a given number, namely n -- but it's not clear if the subset is *also* required to contain exactly some given number k of numbers.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You have a number `n`. You need to find `k` numbers such that their sum is equal to `n` and also such that the product of these `k` numbers is the largest among all such sets of `k` numbers that you can find.

Comment: I see.  And is the set of available numbers (i.e., the ground set) also given?

Comment: @j_random_hacker No. For example `n=10` and `k=3`. Then the possible sets are say `1,1,8`, `1,2,7`.... and so on (all of them). Since the set `3,3,4` produces the highest product (`36`), the output should be `3,3,4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one idea I am having now.

If the number is `n`, and if it is perfectly divisible by `k`, then we have the number `n/k` occurring `k` times, which makes the condition for the sum valid. Also, notice that in this case when we use `n/k` where `k` divides `n` perfectly the result of the multiplication of the result will be maximum. If it is not a perfect divisor, then we can find `ceil(n/k)*k` and multiply `ceil(n/k)` `k-1` times and the last integer can be found by `n - (ceil(n/k) * (k-1))`.

Assuming the `n_i` values can be same.

**EDIT**

I have some very broken math, but here is a proof why to make `n1` and `n2` will have to be equal, for `n1 * n2` maximum when `A = n1 + n2`.

```
A = n1 + n2
n2 = A - n1;

P = n1 * n2
P = n1 * (A - n1) = A * n1 - n1^2

Differentiating P with respect to n1

dP/dn1 = A - 2 * n1 

To find the inflection point, we do dP/dn1 = 0 and solve

A - 2 * n1 = 0
n1 = A/2

which indicates n1 = A/2 and therefore n1 = n2

Which tells to make to make P maximum (as the double differentiation is negative), we need to have n1 = n2
```

I think this proof can be extended to `k` variables? Maybe someone can extend this answer.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta: Still thinking on this. I think this should work fine. But until a mathematical proof is given the answer will not be complete.

Comment: Yes this is working fine. I'm looking for a mathematical proof too. Maybe I should shift this question to math stackexchange.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta, Not sure if to move or post a specific question (if it already does not exist). But I think extending the proof above in this answer for multi variables may get you somewhere.

Comment: Proof just follows from the concavity of the log. No need for differentiation (see my answer).

Comment: @vib: Yes, it took a bit time to get it.

Answer (score 14):

Maximizing the product `n1*n2*..*nk` is equivalent to maximizing its logarithm `log(n1*n2*..*nk) = log(n1)+log(n2)+ .. +log(nk)`, subject to the constraint `n1+..+nk = n`

Because the logarithm is a concave function, this maximum will be attained on a k-uplets such that no two values differ by more than two (because `log((a+b)/2) >= (log(a)+log(b))/2`. This implies that, defining `x = floor(n/k)`, you can restrict yourself to the case where each `n_i` belongs to `{x,x+1}`.

This further implies that you can determine exactly the subset: if you let `a` be such that `a*x+(k-a)*(x+1) = n`, then the maximal subset will be a permutation of
`n1 = x, n2 = x, .., n_a = x, n_{a+1} = x+1, .., nk = x+1.`
The equation on `a` can be explicitly solved and yields `a = k*(ceil(n/k))-n`.